# Is it possible to use Selenium 2 WebDriverWait with ColdFusion?

Tags: coldfusion, selenium-webdriver, coldfusion-10

from http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp it shows the following Java sample code

```
(new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
  public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
    return d.getTitle().toLowerCase().startsWith("cheese!");
  }
});
```

Is it possible to write the code above in CFML, maybe with help of CF10's [dynamic proxy](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSe61e35da8d318518-106e125d1353e804331-7ff9.html)?

It would be awesome if we can get CF10's [closure](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSe61e35da8d31851842acbba1353e848b35-7fff.html) to work with the code sample above, but it doesn't seem like it'll work because of the expected Java interface and Java return type, am I correct?

Comment: I've come to a conclusion that porting WebDriverWait over to CFML with `sleep()` and while loop would be the safest bet. Then make use of CF10's closure to mimic the official API above.  Awesome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure which is the better option. But it is possible using a dynamic proxy. Just create a cfc that implements the `ExpectedCondition` interface:

```
component {
    public boolean function apply(Any d) {
        return d.getTitle().toLowerCase().startsWith("cheese!");
    } 
}
```

Then create an instance of the proxy and pass it into the constructor of `WebDriverWait`

```
<cfscript>
    driver = createObject("java", "org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver").init();
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");

    by = createObject("java", "org.openqa.selenium.By");
    element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));

    WriteDump("Page title is: "& driver.getTitle());

    element.sendKeys(["Cheese!"]);
    element.submit();

    conditionProxy = createDynamicProxy("test.ExpectedConditionProxy", ["org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition"]); 
    WebDriverWait = createObject("java", "org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait");
    WebDriverWait.init(driver, 10).until( conditionProxy );
    WriteDump("Page title is: "& driver.getTitle());

    driver.quit();
</cfscript>
```

Comment: Thank you! you sure `"org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition"` will be enough to satisfy `org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition<Boolean>`?   I don't have CF10 installed here, did the code you post work?

Comment: also, is `Any` for `d` fine for `apply()` when the interface expects `WebDriver`? thx

Comment: Yep, it works with CF10.  Since CF is loosely typed, you can ignore the java generics  `<Boolean>` (they do not apply in CF) and just implement `ExpectedCondition`. Also, type `Any` is fine because CF does not support class names in the function signature (only component paths or the standard types). So you have to use type `Any`. But it is not a problem as the code automatically passes in a `WebDriver` object where needed.

Comment: reading "Selenium 2 Testing Tools Beginner's Guide" makes me want to port over the @findBy annotation to `<cfproperty>`... lol